# Interpretation of Binomial R.V. Proposition

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> > If $X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $(n, p)$, where
> >     $0 < p < 1$, then as $k$ goes from $0$ to $n$, $P\{X = k\}$ first increases monotonically and then decreases monotonically, reaching its largest value when $k$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $(n + 1)p$.

I am trying to understand this proposition, it is not clear the meaning not the proof. The proof of this, it's just considering $P\{X = k\}/P\{X = k − 1\}$ and determining for what values of k it is greater or less than 1.

My question is how is this applicable in real life?, How to well understand this proposition?. Is it just a rate to compare probabilities?

Please, if someone could give me your opinions, I will appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: It can be used to find mode of the distribution.

Comment: It is a very useful fact if you want to make estimates. For example, suppose $n$ is very large, and you want to estimate the probability that $X$ is between $a$ and $b$. If you know that $b < p(n+1)$ and you have some upper bound for $P(X = b)$, then you immediately have an upper bound for $P(X \in [a,b])$. This is just one simple example. In reality, it’s extremely situational and hard to predict when an understanding of the monotonicity of $P(X=k)$ will be useful. Generally you can use it in combination with other known facts to get new inequalities. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, Thank you.